# Use of correct words

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, conjunctions

One of my friends says that

> It will not be better until it will not stop raining.

is not grammatical, but he could not explain why. What is wrong about this sentence?

Comment: It will not be better until it does not stop raining./ It will not be better until the rain does not stop. Are these ok?

Comment: Here it does not show 'not': Let's wait until the rain stops. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/until?q=until

Comment: Short answer: we don't use *will* in the second part of a sentence like this, because you should think of "will" as meaning "is in the future".  You wouldn't say "It will not be better until *stopping raining is in the future*", right?  because what you mean is it will not be better until stopping raining is an actual fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

The first is less a matter of grammar and more a matter of usage. Put simply, we do not use **will** in a clause that begins with a conjunction related to *time.* These include **until, when, after, before, as soon as**, and so on.

I suppose there are some rare exceptions.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conjunctions-time#:%7E:text=Non%2Dfinite%20clauses-,Warning,-%3A) summarizes the rule but adds little to what I have said. I cite it only as a reputable authority.

The second problem is the negation. The two instances of **not** cancel each other. Either of the following will work:

> It will not be better until it stops raining.
>
> It will be better when it stops raining.

However, we tend to focus such sentences on the *change* rather than the *state*. So the following sound more natural:

> It will not **get** better until it stops raining.
>
> It will **get** better when it stops raining.

Comment: Also, it's illogical! Presumably you want it to stop raining instead of _not_ stopping.

Comment: I also wish to know about two negations, is 'not' in the clause with 'until' not grammatical? but even it changes the meaning, right?

Comment: @English-Seeker You should avoid double negatives. They sound funny and they're often difficult to interpret. In your original example, I couldn't understand if you believed it would be better if the rain stopped, or if the rain never stopped.