# "will call" or "call"?

Tags: phrase-usage, tense, phrases

> Wait here until I will call you.

Is using *will call* in this sentence the correct tense, or not?

Comment: ...see also [Use of correct words](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/315809/use-of-correct-words), asking about *It will not be better until it will not stop raining.*

Answer (score 1):

It is "wait here until I call you" because you already depict a future tense using "until", using "will" is repetitive of this future tense.